# Mod_Rewrite Subdomain/Path Rewriting Issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an existing rule in place to rewrite:
**subdomain.domain.com**

to this format:
**domain.com/directory/index.aspx?id=subdomain**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]<br/>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]<br/>
RewriteRule ^$ /directory/index.aspx?id=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I need to update this to support:
**subdomain.domain.com/foo**

to this format:
**domain.com/directory/foo.aspx?id=subdomain**
I've tried to make the following changes to my existing rule without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com/(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /directory/%2.aspx?id=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

It doesn't appear that the second RewriteCond is being matched.  Am I missing something easy?  Should this be handled differently?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP_HOST variable contains the value in the HTTP "Host:" header -- that is, in your case, "subdomain.domain.com". The trailing URI (slash, etc.) is not there.

You need to match that part of the URL in your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]<br/>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]<br/>
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$ /directory/$1.aspx?id=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Salut,

Jordi.